# angularjs routing with api shows undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, express

This are my files
app.js for routing

```
angular
.module('ebookApp', ['ngRoute']).config(config);

function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
       .when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'angular/ebook-list/ebookList.html',
            controller: EbookController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/ebook/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'angular/ebook-display/ebookDisplay.html',
            controller: EbookController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'
          });
          $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ebookApp">
<head>
  <title>Ebook App</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <base href="/">

</head>

<body>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="text-muted text-center">
        <a href="http://fullstacktraining.com" target="_blank"><img src="/images/fullstacktraining_logo.png" height="26" alt="Full Stack Training"/></a>
      </p>

      <p class="text-muted text-center">
        <small>&copy; 2016 Full Stack Training Ltd</small>
      </p>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="angular/app.js"></script>
  <script src="angular/ebook-data-factory/ebook-data-factory.js"></script>
  <script src="angular/ebook-list/ebook.list.js"></script> 
  <script src="angular/ebook-display/ebook.display.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

display.js

```
    angular
.module('ebookApp')
.controller('EbookController',EbookController);

function EbookController($http, $route, $routeParams, ebookDataFactory,) {
    var vm = this;
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.get('/api/ebooks/' + id).then(function(response) {
      vm.ebook = response.data;
    });
  };
```

list.js

```
  angular
.module('ebookApp')
.controller('EbookController', EbookController);

function EbookController($route, $routeParams, ebookDataFactory) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Ebook App'

    ebookDataFactory.ebookList().then(function(response){
        vm.ebooks = response.data;
    });
}
```

the code does basically two things that is to show list of ebooks which it successfully does but displaying each one of them it gives the an error like a BLANK PAGE or this `GET http://localhost:7080/api/ebooks/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)` the id is in api which does exists but it still gives error. Please help.

Comment: Is there a reason that `list.js` and `display.js` are identical?

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager sorry my bad check it now

Comment: You might try using the quoted version of the controller name in `app.js`. So `'EbookController'` instead of just `EbookController`. It might be trying to use your plain function declarations of `EbookController` instead of the actual Angular controller. You should really give those separate names, tho.